# Design patterns for console commands

Tags: c#, console

I've made a pretty standard console in which you type a command and it does something. However, the issue that comes to my mind is scaling: if I want to add hundreds of commands, I have to manually add a new `Command` instance for each one individually, which is... less than ideal.

The full code is stored in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/ArtOfCode-/ConsolePlus).

#### Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ConsolePlus.Commands;

namespace ConsolePlus
{
    public class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The version of the program.
        /// </summary>
        public const string Version = "1.0.0.0";

        public static CommandRegistry<Command> Registry = new CommandRegistry<Command>();

        /// <summary>
        /// The application's entry point.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">The command-line arguments passed to the program.</param>
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CommandHandler.RegisterCommands();

            Console.WriteLine("ConsolePlus v." + Version);
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write(">>> ");
                string line = Console.ReadLine();
                List<string> parts = line.Split(' ').ToList<string>();
                string commandName = parts[0];
                parts.RemoveAt(0);
                string[] commandArgs = parts.ToArray<string>();

                try
                {
                    string result = Registry.Execute(commandName, commandArgs);
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] {1}", commandName, result);
                    }
                }
                catch (CommandNotFoundException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("[ConsolePlus] No such command.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### CommandRegistry.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsolePlus
{
    public class CommandRegistry<T>
        where T : ICommand
    {
        private Dictionary<string, T> register;

        public CommandRegistry()
        {
            register = new Dictionary<string, T>();
        }

        public CommandRegistry(params T[] commands)
            : this()
        {
            foreach (T command in commands)
            {
                register.Add(command.Name, command);
            }
        }

        public T GetCommand(string name)
        {
            if (register.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                return register[name];
            }
            else
            {
                throw new CommandNotFoundException(name);
            }
        }

        public string Execute(string name, string[] args)
        {
            if (register.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                return register[name].Execute(args);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new CommandNotFoundException(name);
            }
        }

        public void RegisterCommand(T command)
        {
            register.Add(command.Name, command);
        }
    }
}
```

#### ICommand.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsolePlus
{
    public interface ICommand
    {
        string Name { get; set; }

        string HelpText { get; set; }

        bool IsPrivileged { get; set; }

        string Execute(string[] args);
    }
}
```

#### Command.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsolePlus
{
    public class Command : ICommand
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string HelpText { get; set; }

        public bool IsPrivileged { get; set; }

        private Func<string[], string> method;

        public Command(string name, bool privileged, string help, Func<string[], string> commandMethod)
        {
            Name = name;
            IsPrivileged = privileged;
            HelpText = help;
            method = commandMethod;
        }

        public string Execute(string[] args)
        {
            return method.Invoke(args);
        }
    }
}
```

#### CommandHandler.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsolePlus.Commands
{
    public class CommandHandler
    {
        public static List<Command> AllCommands = new List<Command>
        {
            new Command("clear", false, ClearCommand.HelpText, ClearCommand.CommandMethod),
            new Command("exit", false, ExitCommand.HelpText, ExitCommand.CommandMethod)
        };

        public static void RegisterCommands()
        {
            foreach (Command command in AllCommands)
            {
                Program.Registry.RegisterCommand(command);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And just for illustration (the other `*Command` classes are very similar):

#### ClearCommand.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsolePlus.Commands
{
    class ClearCommand
    {
        public static string HelpText = "Clears the console screen.";

        public static string CommandMethod(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment, to add another command, I have to create another class and add another `new Command` line to the `CommandHandler.RegisterCommands` method - not ideal. Reviews of this specifically, and if there are any better ways to do this, would be very useful - though of course, any review is a good thing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Why do you have the `Command` class? Why not make life much simpler for yourself by making `AllCommands` a `List<ICommand>`, and having classes like `ClearCommand` implement `ICommand`?

You can then query your assembly file for classes where `ICommand` is implemented; that way you don't even need to fill `AllCommands` "by hand":

```
AllCommands = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
    .Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ICommand))
                && x.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null)
    .Select(x => Activator.CreateInstance(x) as ICommand);
```

Also, does `AllCommands` need to be called `AllCommands`? Can't it just be called `Commands`?

I would also recommend to remove the setters from the properties in `ICommand`. That way you'd end up with something like this:

```
public interface ICommand
{
    string Name { get; }

    string HelpText { get; }

    bool IsPrivileged { get; }

    string Execute(string[] args);
}

public class ClearCommand : ICommand
{
    public string Name { get { return "clear"; } }

    public string HelpText { get { return "Clears the console screen."; } }

    public bool IsPrivileged { get { return false; } }

    public string Execute(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Reading an answer like this makes me hyped to write C#!